# issuing an USSD command /wt trailing encoding argument

Tags: encoding, at-command, ussd

I am using smstools3 for operating an USB-based surf stick for sending SMSes. I am working on querying the balance of a prepaid SIM card. The stick is a ZTE MF112 from China, the provider is eplus from Germany. This seems relevant as the response to a balance query contains an umlaut (ä).

Speaking directly to the modem (via cu /dev/ttyU0.2) I can perform a query:

```
AT+CUSD=1,"*100#",15
OK

+CUSD: 0,"00490068007200200047007500740068006100620065006E0020006200650074007200E400670074003A00200039002C003900370020002E",72
```

which response eventually translates to

```
Ihr Guthaben beträgt: 9,97 .
```

However, smstools3 has problems whith this. It appears that the encoding (,15) is omitted in the request and I have no way of supplying it.

Question: is there a way of setting the encoding globally in an init command like AT+CSCS?